# Support in Ethereum for PoWs algos other than Ethash

Tags: proof-of-work, hash-algorithm, ethash

I read that Ethereum uses Ethash as proof of work algorithm. But since there are other PoWs like NeoScrypt (used by Phoenixcoin), scryptJane (used by LEOcoin).

Is it possible to use the above mentioned algorithms as PoWs.(Obviously it could be done but the gist of the question is how much effort (changes in source code) is required to do so). Does changes in only file replacing the algorithm will do or would it be herculean task.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would be possible, but you would have to make every one follow your fork. Why would we do this ? Ethash is nice and Casper proof of stake algorithm will come soon (I hope) so mining will be over.

Comment: continue from previous comment.
May you please tell which file needs to be changed.

Comment: No, sorry I'm not digging so deep in ethereum code.